# Javascript Object to querystring using reduce

Tags: javascript, object, reduce

I'm having trouble to apply a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to an `Object` to get it in a querystring format.

I want this:

```
> var obj = {a: 1, b: "213123", c: null, d:false}
> obj2querystring(obj);
a=1&b=213123&c=null&d=false
```

So far, the close I have got is this:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(prev, curr){
    return prev + '&' + curr + '=' + obj[curr];
}, '');
```

which gives me:

```
&a=1&b=213123&c=null&d=false
```

Is there an easier way to achieve this without have to prepend the initialValue and remove the `&` later?

---

**EDIT: This question is old and today we can just use `new URLSearchParams(object).toString()`, [safely](https://caniuse.com/urlsearchparams)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of doing a `reduce`, a cleaner way would be `map` and `join`.

```
Object.keys(obj).map(function(x){
    return x + '=' + obj[x];
}).join('&');
```

- **map** makes and array like this: `["a=1", "b=213123", "c=null", "d=false"]`
- **join** turns it into a query string: `a=1&b=213123&c=null&d=false`

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` with `join`:

```
return Object.keys(obj).map(function(i) {
  return i + '=' + obj[i];
}).join('&');
```

And it's important to use `encodeURIComponent` on both sides of the queryString:

```
return Object.keys(obj).map(function(i) {
  return encodeURIComponent(i) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[i]);
}).join('&');
```

If you need the queryString back at anytime:

```
location.search.slice(1).split('&').map(function(i) {
  var arr = i.split('=');
  var a = {};
  a[decodeURIComponent(arr[0])] = arr[1] ? decodeURIComponent(arr[1]) : void 0;
  return a;
}).reduce(function(a, b) {
  var key = Object.keys(b)[0];
  a[key] = b[key];
  return a;
});
```